# How to I get two inputs at same time in flask

Tags: python, flask, input

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,  request
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])

def Input_1():
name1 = ""
if request.method == 'POST':
name1 = request.form.get("name1", "0")
return render_template('index.html', DataFromPython1 = name1)

def Input_2():
name2 = ""
if request.method == "POST":
name2 = request.form.get("name2", "0")
return render_template('index.html', DataFromPython2 = name2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run()
```

This is my code

First function works well, but second function dose not work as first function.

I gave input in second box but nothing happened

what do I have to do to get two inputs at same time?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that only `Input_1()` will run, for the `/` route.

The solution is to use **one** route and **one** function:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
# ^^^ prefer one import per line


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name1 = request.form.get('name1', '0')
        name2 = request.form.get('name2', '0')
        return render_template('index.html',
                               DataFromPython1=name1,
                               DataFromPython2=name2)
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

If its a `POST` request, then retrieve all the values you want from the `form`, and pass them to be rendered.

Most likely, if its a `GET` request you want to just load `index.html`, so I've added that in as well.

Comment: Wow... Thank you so much~!